# Относительный путь (алгоритм)

Tags: java, алгоритм

Одному знакомому дали такое задание на экзамене:

```
Дан абсолютный путь для файла(Unix-style) - необходимо упростить его. 

Принятые обозначения: 
/ - переход в папку; 
.. - переход к на шаг выше по каталогу;
. - остаться в текущем каталоге. 

Пример пути для файла и результат упрощения: 

1. (/home/ -> /home), 2. (/a/./b/../../c -> /c)
```

Он не смог решить. Мне показывает, я тоже не смог, потому что не понял суть вопроса, ну вот никак.

Сейчас нашел ответ:

```
private String homePath(String pathString) {
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();

    int i = 0;
    StringBuilder w = new StringBuilder();

    while (i < pathString.length()) {
        if (pathString.charAt(i) == '/') {
            updateStack(w.toString(), stack);
            w = new StringBuilder();
        } else {
            w.append(pathString.charAt(i));
        }
        i++;
    }

    updateStack(w.toString(), stack);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        sb.insert(0, "/" + stack.pop());
    }

    if (sb.toString().equals("")){
        return "/";
    } else {
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

private static void updateStack(String w, Stack<String> stack) {
    if (w.equals("..") && !stack.isEmpty()) {
        stack.pop();
    }
    if (!w.equals(".") && !w.equals("") && !w.equals("..")) {
        stack.push(w);
    }
}
```

Я понимаю путь обычный, юниксовский.

Но вот мне не понятно, что значит упростить? Зачем?

Answer (score 0):

> Что значит упростить?

Значит, представить абсолютный путь к файлу в самом коротком виде. Используя `.` и `..`, путь к одному и тому же файлу можно указать бесконечным множеством разных способов. Например:

```
/a/b/c
/a/./b/c
/a/./b/./c
/a/b/../b/c
/a/../a/./b/../b/c
```

Все эти пути указывают на один и тот же файл.

> Зачем?

Затем, что короткий путь - самый читаемый. А ещё оптимизация пути к файлу - это отличная задачка на использование стэка.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ. Не совсем понял, "." - остаться в текущем каталоге, но что означает /a/./b/c - то есть откуда взялась точка посередине?

Comment: Ну... я её поставил. Просто чтобы продемонстрировать, то `/a/b/c` и `/a/./b/c` - это один и тот же путь. Путь `/a/b/c` интерпретируется как "перейти в каталог `a`, перейти в каталог `b`, найти файл `c`", путь `/a/./b/c` - как "перейти в каталог `a`, не менять каталог, перейти в каталог `b`, найти файл `c`". В обоих случаях мы приходим к одному и тому же файлу, но во втором делаем больше действий.

Comment: Да, я понял что вы поставили)). Вот я хотел узнать о " не менять каталог," вы написали  "не менять каталог, перейти в каталог b", так что значит не менять каталог, то есть и в первом варианте как мне кажется, мы не меняем каталог? Извините, если я туплю.

Comment: Путь у файлу разбирается по шагам, на каждом шаге берётся один сегмент, ограниченный слешами. И если в этом сегменте имя папки, то ОС переходит в эту папку, если `..`, то переходит в родительскую папку, а если `.`, то не делает ничего. Последнее и есть "не менять каталог". В первом варианте мы на каждом шаге переходим между каталогами, в вариантах 2, 3 и 5 есть шаги, на которых мы остаёмся в том каталоге, в который пришли, в вариантах 4 и 5 есть шаги, на которых мы переходим в родительский каталог. Не знаю, как ещё это объяснить.